# Array sorting - two staff arrays sorted into one staff array with no duplicates

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, conditional-statements

I have two arrays that contain staff members. One array contains ALL the staff of the hotel as `Staff` objects, another array contains only the staff that are currently working today as `Staff` objects.

I have a custom object;

```
Staff.h

NSString * staff_id;
NSString * staff_name;
BOOL isWorking
```

My final array is to contain all staff members, with only one instance of each (so each Staff member only appears once in the array) and with the `Staff` objects with the BOOL value set to `NO/FALSE/0` where the staff member is working. `isWorking` is set to TRUE by default.

I have tried a combination of different conditional statements but I have still getting duplicates. My conditional statement is definitely not optimal. I was trying to start furthest out and work to a more optimised solution.

```
-(void)sortStaff{

    NSMutableArray * fullArray = [NSMutableArray array];//contain full array of staff objects
    NSMutableArray * idArray = [NSMutableArray array];//contain all staff ids in order to check whether they already exist in the array or not
    NSMutableArray * noDuplicatesArray = [NSMutableArray array];//the array to hold no duplicates

    //loop through all staff working
    for (int i =1; i<self.workingStaffArray.count; i++) {
        Staff * workingStaffMember = [[Staff alloc] init];
        workingStaffMember = [self.workingStaffArray objectAtIndex:i];

        //loop through all the staff of the hotel
        for (int j=0; j<self.allStaffArray.count; j++) {
            Staff * allStaffMember =[[Staff alloc] init];

            allStaffMember=[self.allStaffArray objectAtIndex:j];

            //if the workingStaffMember id is not equal to the allStaffMember id then they are not working today at the hotel
            if ([workingStaffMember.staff_id intValue] != [allStaffMember.staff_id intValue ])      {
                 //set boolean to NO - they are not working today
                 allStaffMember.isWorking=NO;

                 //add the staff id to idArray
                 [idArray addObject:allStaffMember.staff_id];

                 //loop through the objs
                 for (NSString * obj in idArray)
                 {

                    //add the staff id to the noDuplicatesArray if it already exists
                    if (![noDuplicatesArray containsObject:obj])
                    {

                        [noDuplicatesArray addObject: obj];
                        //if it doesnt already exist in the noduplicatesArray it means we have not passed it already, add the staff object to the fullArray
                        [fullArray addObject:allStaffMember];
                    }
                }


            }

        }
    }

    //The final array that already contains the working staff members, but the staff who are not working today are to be added to the end.
    [self.workingStaffArray addObjectsFromArray:fullArray];
}
```

I am always looking to improve so any helpful thoughts and constructive criticism is welcome.

The result at the moment is that the `self.workingStaffArray` contains all the working staff for today, as well as all the Staff who working at the hotel.

This line;

```
if ([workingStaffMember.staff_id intValue] != [allStaffMember.staff_id intValue ])
```

is letting me down for sure, but a better more optimal solution is welcome.

Thanks in advance :)

***EDIT***: The problem seems to be that because of the `loop through all staff` there is an instance where every staff member will get added. For example, I want the outcome to be based on the following example;

```
Working array contains:

Staff{
staff_name = @"Charlie";
staff_id = @"121"
isWorking= YES;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"Sam";
staff_id = @"122"
isWorking= YES;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"BEN";
staff_id = @"124"
isWorking= YES;
}
```

The all Staff array contains (with default BOOL);

```
Staff{
staff_name = @"Charlie";
staff_id = @"121"
isWorking= YES;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"Sam";
staff_id = @"122"
isWorking= YES;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"BEN";
staff_id = @"123"
isWorking= YES;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"PETER";
staff_id = @"124"
isWorking= YES;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"Louis";
staff_id = @"125"
isWorking= YES;
}
```

The finalArray is to looking like this:

```
Staff{
staff_name = @"Charlie";
staff_id = @"121"
isWorking= YES;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"Sam";
staff_id = @"122"
isWorking= YES;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"BEN";
staff_id = @"123"
isWorking= YES;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"PETER";
staff_id = @"124"
isWorking= NO;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"Louis";
staff_id = @"125"
isWorking= NO;
}
```

But the current implementation gives:

```
Staff{
staff_name = @"Charlie";
staff_id = @"121"
isWorking= YES;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"Sam";
staff_id = @"122"
isWorking= YES;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"BEN";
staff_id = @"123"
isWorking= YES;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"Charlie";
staff_id = @"121"
isWorking= NO;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"Sam";
staff_id = @"122"
isWorking= NO;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"BEN";
staff_id = @"123"
isWorking= NO;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"PETER";
staff_id = @"124"
isWorking= NO;
}
Staff{
staff_name = @"Louis";
staff_id = @"125"
isWorking= NO;
}
```

***EDIT2 *** I was getting incorrect results. Just to make things clear in case it is hard to understand: I have two arrays. One contains the staff working today, and One contains all the staff in the hotel. I want to combine the two into one array of Staff objects. This array contains all the staff who are working today, and those that are not working today. This third array will contain all the staff members but the only difference is that they will have the appropriate BOOl value `isWorking`

Comment: @matt thanks, please see the edit for further information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly implement the `isEqual` method of your `Staff` object:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    if (![object isKindOfClass:[Staff class]])
        return NO;
    Staff *other = (Staff *)object;
    return self.staff_id == other.staff_id;
}
```

And secondly use an `NSMutableSet` to ensure you have a unique set of objects:

```
NSMutableSet *staffSet = [NSMutableSet new];
....
[staffSet addObject:obj];
```

(I think this covers most of the issues in your question; if not then please add a comment).

Comment: Thanks Droppy, but how do you want me to use this code?

Comment: Well you can use `if (![workingStaffMember isEqual:allStaffMember])` in the statement you highlight and you can avoid using `noDuplicateArray` and instead use the *set* object.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to use `NSMutableSet`? It would be great if you could elaborate on why to do the following in the above answer? I think it would be beneficial.

Comment: @DevC come on, do some learning on your own. You've been pointed to NSSet twice. It solves the problem of uniqueness perfectly. Droppy's answer is brilliant and tells you all you need to know. Listen to what you are told and do some thinking. Here is my intro to NSSet, if it will help jog your mind: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch10.html#_nsset_and_friends

Comment: @matt thanks, apologies, I was using SO as my learning tool. I take on board what you say. Although useful, I found it abstract as he mentioned the above originally but didnt explain where or why to use. I provided my code above, and mentioned it was working appropriately but I didnt know why. thanks for the link.

Comment: @matt * (typos above) but didnt explain where or why to use it. I provided my code above, and mentioned it WASNT working appropriately but I didnt know why.